What function describes the curve created by these points?
When $n$ is even, the lines $n^x$ and $x^n$ cross three times. One of them is in the negatives. What is the function for the curve these intersects are on?

By using Geogebra or Desmos, you should be able to make a conjecture. Please try to work at least a little before asking on this site...

They are public domain tools. It is very easy to learn to use them by drawing the curves and attempting differents values of n

Take logs of both sides, separate variables and find $x=n$

If you are asking "on what curve do the zeros of $x^n=n^x$ that is like asking "on what curve do the zeros of $nx=x^2$ lay?". For the latter we can solve to say that the zeros are are on the curve $x=0$ and $x=n$. If that is what you mean by your question, you can go to live.sympy.org and type solve(x**n-n**x,x) at the prompt and that will give an answer for the curve $x = f(n)$ (and the name will direct your studies from there).

It seems to me that while $x=n$ is a solution to the original equation, $x=0$ is not as that gives $0=1$ unless $n=0$ as well

I changed equations to something more readily tractable, $nx = x^2$.
